# Making Shallow Copy instead of Deep copy

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

Hi I am trying to make the shallow copy of data instead of deep copy as shown below but on UI it is not coming properly kindly someone help me out:

```
Deep Copy : --JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.ABC[this.test].TEF))

and when i am making shallow copy then : (this.ABC[this.test].TEF).map(element => Object.assign({}, { ...element }))
```

on UI in the second case it is coming as [object][object] is there any way for this:

is there any way we can match the following values on UI:

Answer (score 3):

A shallow copy is trivial; just use the spread operator:

```
this.ABC[this.test].TEF = [...this.ABC[this.test].TEF];
```

The version you wrote that you called a shallow copy is actually a semi-deep copy; you're copying the first level of the elements. That wasn't quite correct, either, it should be:

```
this.ABC[this.test].TEF).map(element => Object.assign({}, element));
```